# WCF Service is unable to locate System.Net.Http in release build only

Tags: c#, .net, http, clickonce

I'm working on an error that I'm getting in a WinForms application that was recently updated from .Net framework 4.5.2 to 4.7. The issue occurs only *after* the application has been deployed. The error is originating from inside a WCF service (.svc) that I'm using. The specific error text I'm getting is:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.1,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

In attempting to resolve this issue, I adjusted the App.Config file to bindingRedirect from `System.Net.Http version 4.1.1.1` to `4.3.2` (which doesn't actually exist).

This **resolved** the issue with the service; however, when I made a call to `System.Net.Http` to download a string, the call failed. Presumably, this is because I directed System.Net.Http to use a dependency that does not actually exist (4.3.2).

This means currently I have a choice: either the service works, or calls directly to System.Net.Http work, but not both. Is anyone aware of how to make the service able find System.Net.Http 4.1.1.1? It is installed via NuGet... just seemingly not recognized unless:
1) I issue a binding redirect to a version of `System.Net.Http` that doesn't actually exist.
OR
2) I run the program in debug/release mode from Visual Studio (deployed release doesn't work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the issue, after several days of trouble. System.Net.Http is not published as it is supposed to be. It is a known issue (that is resolved, in theory), found here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/p/httpclient/

```
Issue 8

Symptom

ClickOnce applications targeting .NET Framework 4.0 that reference the Microsoft.Net.Http package may experience a TypeLoadException or other errors after being installed.

Resolution

This occurs because ClickOnce fails to deploy certain required assemblies. As a workaround, do the following:
1.Right-click on the project and choose Add Existing Item
2.Browse to the HttpClient net40 package folder
3.In the File name text box enter *.*
4.Holding CTRL, select System.Net.Http.dll and System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll
5.Click the down-arrow next to the Add button and choose Add as Link
6.In Solution Explorer, holding CTRL select System.Net.Http.dll and System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll
7.Right-click the selection, choose Properties and change Copy to Output Directory to Copy always
8.Republish
```